# How to update UI from another Thread using handler in android?

Tags: android

I am developing android app in which I have to send some data to server and receive some response from server for this I am using AsynkTask. Right now I am getting response in onPostexecute method of Asynktask and update UI according to server response in onPostexecute method of AsynkTask. what I want is to update UI not from onPostexecute method but from another thread using handler to reduce load from main Thread.How can I do that kindly tell me .

here is my code of AsynkTask:-

```
private class LoginAttempt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        CProgressBar.getInstance().showProgressBar(getActivity(), "Please wait while Logging...");// showing progress ..........
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        getLoginDetails();// getting login details from editText...........
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        m_oJsonsResponse = new CJsonsResponse();
        isFirstLogin = true;
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(s_szLoginUrl);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agentCode", s_szMobileNumber);
            jsonObject.put("pin", s_szPassword);
            jsonObject.put("firstloginflag", m_oLoginSession.isLogin());
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            //  httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");   ///not required
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            System.out.print("InputStream...." + inputStream.toString());
            System.out.print("Response...." + httpResponse.toString());

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            System.out.print("statusLine......" + statusLine.toString());
            ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    s_szresult = m_oJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                }
            } else
                s_szresult = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return s_szresult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CProgressBar.getInstance().hideProgressBar();// hide progressbar after getting response from server......
                try {
                    m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(response);// getting response from server

                    getResponse();// getting response from server ........

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void getResponse() throws JSONException {
        if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {
            m_oLoginSession.setLoginData(s_szResponseMobile, s_szResponsePassword);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CDealMainListing()).commit();
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "You are successfully Logged In");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Agentcode Can Not Be Empty")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Pin Can Not Be Empty")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "Please Enter Password");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid PIN")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "Please enter correct Password");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Subscriber/Agent Blocked due to Wrong Attempts")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "You are blocked as You finished your all attempt");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "Connection Lost ! Please Try Again");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Subscriber/Agent Not Found")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "User not found ! Kindly Regiter before Login");
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("OTP not verify")) {
            CToastMessage.getInstance().showToast(getActivity(), "Otp not Verify ! Kindly Generate Otp on Sign Up");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a Handler here?  I see no advantage.

Comment: To reduce load from main thread

Comment: reduce heavy loading from main Thread

Comment: The Handler you're using still schedules the Runnable on the main thread.  It's not helping.

Comment: but while running shows a message "applicatio is doing too much work on its main thread"

Comment: Using a Handler is not going to fix this problem for you. Try to identify what operation executed on the main (UI) thread is taking so long and move it to `doInBackground`.

Comment: Is it possible to Update Ui from doinBackground which I had done in onPostexecute .if yes then how tell me

Comment: No, you should only update the UI from the UI thread. But you should move anything else, especially I/O (whether network or local) into `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Handler`. Do the heavy lifting in an `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` and then only update the UI in `onPostExecute`. The `onPostExecute` method is called on the same thread as the `execute()` call so if you start on the UI thread, you end on the UI thread.

```
protected void onPostExecute(final String response) {
    super.onPostExecute(response);
    CProgressBar.getInstance().hideProgressBar();
    ...
}
```

Posting a message to a `Handler` or using `runOnUiThread` will not really buy you more. It would be essentially the same thing, only executed a little bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Any way if you want to update task in UI thread could be use `runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInfo.setText(str);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hey I want to update Ui FROM EXTERNAL THREAD NOT IN ONpOSTEXECUTE

Comment: You can use it anywhere, even like doInBackground!

Comment: but in my case while I am using in doInbackroung give me error

Answer (score 0):

- You can not update your UI from another thread or from doInBackground() of Asynctask.
- To match your requirement the best you can do is-

  Do all the http request thing and server request and response things in another thread .

  Then when you need to update anything in UI just start a asynctask for this.

  This will make your processing faster as you are multithreading.

Hope this answer helped you.

Comment: give me reference for that

Comment: what reference ? there are program specific logicstics. you can only tell the way. and you have to apply this in your code. please tell what you need ,be specific .

Comment: you make thread as normally done . do you know how to use threads in android ?

Comment: ok so you will apply it like that . and just start Asynctask when you need to change ui

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be useful for you is EventBus, in Which you can update your UI and send message to and from: Activities, Threads, Fragments, ETC.
I recommend trying to use [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).